# Unable to set date in Angular material datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a date which is fetched from the backed as `30-10-2019 (DD-MM-YYYY)` format. I am trying to get this date to be displayed in angular material datepicker but its not displaying the date.

I tried moment and used moment `(this.myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`.toString(); What am I missing? Any other method (without using moment) is also fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Provide the code what you tried with [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have tried moment(this.myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://stackblitz.com/angular/aqegoygyadb

Comment: Hey Paul, yeah but I am not able to get it to show in the datepicker using angular binding. I have a date which is in DD-MM-YYYY format and I need to display it in the datepicker. If I have a date as "Wed Oct 30 2019 20:44:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", it gets displayed, not not 30-10-2019

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
this.date = new Date(this.myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need pass the date format to moment like below and assign that to your formControl or ngModel. Assuming your ngModel is date then code will be

```
this.date = moment(this.myDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Here is the working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9szcc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Allabakash, thanks for your help. I did this.startDate = moment(data.startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').toISOString(); and it worked but its displaying the date in MM/DD/YYY format.

Comment: In the attached code link, there is config with name MY_FORMATS, just change format of *dateInput* inside *display* object to the format you wanted to see.

Comment: Sorry but it did not work, the format is correct, although I tried changing it but it did not work.

Comment: did you change MY_FORMATS ? In the code link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9szcc.  Date format is showing as DD-MM-YYYY only . What format you are expecting ?

Comment: I am expecting DD-MM-YYYY. MY_FORMATS has DD-MM-YYYY so I dont think I have to change it. Here is what I have:

Comment: export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};     this.startDate = moment(rowData.data.startDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').toISOString(); and I tried without the .toISOString() as well.